# 64-bit executables with DMD

Tags: compiler-construction, 64-bit, d

I'm a bit confused about the -m64 switch on the DMD compiler. Specifically, the documentation for it says this:

> Compile a 64 bit executable. The generated object code is in MS-COFF and is meant to be used with the Microsoft Visual Studio 10 or later compiler.

Now, I've tried to use it with my own .d files, and it's always failed with the following message:

> Can't run '\bin\link.exe', check PATH

Does this mean I need to have a copy of Microsoft Visual Studio 10 (or later) to compile 64-bit executables? As you might have guessed, I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: I assumed that this meant that you'd need to use it to work with mixed C code for example. I certainly didn't read it as meaning that you *required* a working visual c++ compiler set up to use the D compiler. Yeah, after it's explained, sure.. it makes sense. But it's not something in my opinion you'd read and realize the implications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generation of 64bit executables on Windows requires configuration of DMD. It does not work out of box unfortunately. It is all explained on the "[Windows notes](http://dlang.org/dmd-windows.html)" page.

In short, you need to set environment variable LINKCMD64 to a valid Microsoft linker. You may do this from the command line, before you run dmd, by executing `set LINKCMD64=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64\link.exe` . Problem with this is that it is a temporal solution. I prefer setting a persistent environment variable LINKCMD64.

"[How to Create a Environmental Variable Windows 7](https://kb.wisc.edu/cae/page.php?id=24500)" is a good article which shows how to create environment variables on Windows 7.

PS. You do not need to buy Visual Studio. [Visual Studio Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-8) (C++) contains the linker. I believe Platform SDK too. There was a package which contains just the compiler, linker and all necessary tools to build Windows applications, but I do not remember the name of that package.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a valid Microsoft linker that I don't have to pay for? Visual Studio is a rather expensive product...

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio Express is free IDE. Install C++ support and voila, you have the linker.

Comment: I've done everything that you suggested. Visual Studio Express has two linkers - one at ``\bin\amd64_x86\link.exe`` and another at ``\bin\link.exe``. I created the path variable just like you said, but I still get the same error message as before, except with a different path in it. To be exact, I get ``Can't run '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\link.exe"', check PATH``, with the other option giving the same error message. Did I miss something?

Comment: I assume one is 32bit, and the second one is 64bit. I would suggest you use amd64_x86 one. Also, be careful whether your LINKCMD64 value is correct (I wonder why are you getting those double-quotes).

Comment: I've corrected the LINKCMD64 value (seems like it doesn't need the quotes), and am using the linker you suggested. Now I get the following error message:
``LINK : fatal error LNK1171: unable to load mspdb120.dll (error code: 126)
--- errorlevel 1171``

I'm still not sure what's going on this time.

Comment: Well MS compiler needs own environment set properly... There is a bat/cmd file somewhere that you should run whenever you want to invoke it. Or, check the environment variables that need to be set, and have them in your own environment. Alternatively, try the VisualD plugin (can be used with the *free* Visual Studio Shell). I rarely do Windows programming, so I can't help you much.